# Query range of data linq c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, date-range

I have a calendar in my website and users can create events of one or more days.
So, in my `Calendar` table I set two fields `Start`(Datetime) and `End`(Datetime).
I want to do a query with a specific date range like from `08/01/2017` to `08/31/2017`.
Now, how can I take all the events that are in this range?
I have to take:

- Events that start in this range and end before or after the range end,
- Events that start before the range and end in this range,
- Events that start before this range but end after this range

Is it possible to do a single query or i have to do three different query?
I hope I explained myself, otherwise ask me...

Comment: @René Vogt: That doesn't cover the third requirement.

Comment: I would say it should be enough to test for `event.End > range.Start && event.Start < range.End` Of course assuming that always event.Start < event.End and range.Start < range.End ...

Comment: Yes, i have to show also the third events because it go through the range.

Comment: @Broge - Do you want events from all 3 cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it should be enough to test for `event.End >= range.Start && event.Start <= range.End`

```
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Range        |-----|
Evt1   |-|                   evt.End < range.Start => false
Evt2                 |-|     evt.Start > range.End => false
Evt3     |-----------|       => true
Evt4     |-------|           => true
Evt5             |-----|     => true
Evt6           |-|           => true
```

Comment: Yes. With this simple conditions I take all the three type of events. Thanks

Comment: I upvoted René because he actually came up with working code.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov That is extacly the third condition: "Events that start before this range but end after this range"

Comment: De nada. I had to do the exact same thing once or twice. I figured it's easiest to get to the correct (and easy/compact) solution if I lay out the requirements visually.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime startRange = new DateTime(2017, 08, 01);
DateTime endRange   = new DateTime(2017, 08, 32);

var events = db.Events
   .Where(e => e.Start >= startRange && startRange <= e.End && e.End >= endRange
            || e.Start <= startRange && e.End >= endRange
            || e.Start <= startRange && endRange >= e.Start && e.End <= endRange);
```

Is this sufficient?

Comment: @RenéVogt: True, now :)

Comment: It works though but @Fildor method is more simple. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements can be boiled down to the facts that:

- the event **starts before the end** of the range **and**
- the event **ends after the start** of the range

(the "and" is important, otherwise events totally outside the range will match, too).

So, this should work:

```
DateTime startRange = new DateTime(2017, 08, 01);
DateTime endRange   = new DateTime(2017, 08, 32);

var events = db.Events.Where(e => e.Start <= rangeEnd && e.End >= rangeStart);
```